# the method .add(node) doesn't allow me to use Button. JavaFX

Tags: javafx

```
package application;
import java.awt.Button;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button btn = new Button("Click Me");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn); //error here

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I was following a tutorial from a YT video and came across this error. It won't let me add a button and it says `The method add(Node) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (Button)`. I tried doing EXACTLY the same as the tutorial showed but the error still remains. I don't understand why this is happening. I'm a total beginner in JavaFX

Comment: wrong import  java.awt.Button;

Comment: This fixed it. I used Ctrl+Shift+O to automatically import them. I guess that not really that reliable.